# Highest populated dimension of an array vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Say i have an single dimension array (to keep it simple). Is there a simple way to tell what the highest index of an element that was explicitly assigned a value? other than to loop through and count? 
I know Ubound finds the highest dimension of the array but that's not what I need. Is there something like Ubound but it only counts populated elements of an array, or the highest index populated?

My array contains strings.
Also, what if the array is multidimensional.

I'm working in excel vba.

Comment: Your wording is unclear... The "highest dimension" of a "single dimension array" is one. Do you mean the largest value in the array?

Comment: It looks like the OP means the highest *index* of an element that was explicitly assigned a value, as opposed to elements that have default values. There's no way to do that in general in VBA, although if you know what kind of values your array might contain, you might get what you want by using one of Excel's functions (such as COUNTA) via 'Application.WorksheetFunction'

Comment: I agree with @jtolle, so a specific answer will have to do based on more details of your array that you need to share.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity / thanks for the comments. I hope my edit clears things up. 
@ jtolle thanks for the correct vocab. I tried out Application.WorksheetFunction.counta but it just seems to tell me the number of elements in the array if arry(1 to 50) it returns 50, if arry(1 to 2, 1 to 3) it return 6=2*3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a short word, no there is no in built mechanism to do this, but if you are looking for a way to hack it, then read on.

It depends on how you are filling up the array. If it is sequential, the easiest would be having a counter.

If it is randomized then you have a bigger challenge of finding the exact index of the last element. One idea, is to start from the maximum and start counting down.

If the array is initialized, you can count the default values and subtract from the ubound.

There are other ideas, but you need to more clearly defined the problem to give us a better chance of answering. Preferably with an example.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using ReDim Preserve as you populate the array.  Thus UBound will work quite nicely for you.   Only the last dimension in a multi dimensional array can be ReDimmed.

Comment: That would work, but it's not entirely practical for what I'm doing, it would just mean I'm ReDim Perserve 'ing all over the place. Which might be okay.  Right now I'm doing a similar thing I'm just keeping track of when I add/remove something to/from the array.

Answer (score 2):

## *Highest populated element of an array*

You could step backwards through a loop until you find the first array element that isn't empty.
This is the equivalent of the "last" populated element.

### **Short answer:**

```
Function HighestPopIdx(ByRef arr) As Long
    For HighestPopIdx = UBound(arr) To LBound(arr) Step -1
        If Not IsEmpty(arr(HighestPopIdx)) Then Exit Function
    Next
End Function
```

---

## **Longer answer:**

To get the ***Highest populated element of an array***, I would use a **`For..Next`** loop with the **`IsEmpty`** function.

(This example is a tad over-complicated, for the sake of demonstration.)

```
Sub demo() '(Hit CTRL+G in the VBE to view the output in the Immediate window.)

    'Make a test ARRAY of 5 elements:
    Dim arr(1 To 5)

    Erase arr '(just to make sure the test is starting 'fresh')

    arr(1) = "X"
    arr(2) = 99
    arr(4) = "Y" '3 of the 5 elements have data (highest one is 4)

    Dim elIdx As Long, highestPopEl As Long
    For elIdx = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If Not IsEmpty(arr(elIdx)) Then highestPopEl = elIdx
    Next elIdx

    Debug.Print "The highest populated element index is " & highestPopEl 'Returns 4

End Sub
```

...or in reverse (first example could be quicker depending on your situation.

---

### Other notes:

Further to @jtolle's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2801028/8112776), neither `Count` nor `CountA` worksheet functions will work:

```
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        Debug.Print "Array WS CountA", .CountA(arr) 'returns 5 (Counts cells)
        Debug.Print "Array WS Count", .Count(arr) 'returns 1 (Counts numbers)
    End With
```

...and further to the comments, showing that arrays & cell ranges function similarly but **not** the same:

```
    'Make a test RANGE of 5 cells
    Dim rge As Range
    Set rge = Range("A1:A5")

    rge.Clear '(maker sure we're starting fresh)

    Range("A1") = "X"
    Range("A2") = 99
    Range("A4") = "Y" '3 of the 5 cells have data

    With Application.WorksheetFunction        
        Debug.Print "Range WS CountA", .CountA(rge) 'returns 3 (Counts values)
        Debug.Print "Range WS Count", .Count(rge)   'returns 1 (Counts numbers)
    End With

   '... and the VBA [Range.Count] method behaves differently:
    Debug.Print "Range VBA .Count", rge.Count 'returns 5 (Counts cells)
```

On the other hand if my "actual" goal was to *do something* to each element in an array, I would use `For..Each` loop with the **`IsEmpty`** function.

```
    'if my actual purpose is to ***do something*** to an ARRAY...
    Debug.Print: Debug.Print "Array [For..Next] :"
    Dim elCnt As Long, el

    For Each el In arr
        If Not IsEmpty(el) Then _
            elCnt = elCnt + 1: Debug.Print "#" & elCnt & ": Element value =", el
    Next el    ' (returns "X", 99, "Y")

    '...and the identical method can be used on a RANGE of cells
    Debug.Print: Debug.Print "Range [For..Next] :"
    Dim clCnt As Long, cl

    For Each cl In rge
        If Not IsEmpty(cl) Then _
            clCnt = clCnt + 1: Debug.Print "#" & clCnt & ": Cell value =", cl
    Next cl    ' (returns "X", 99, "Y")


End Sub
```

---

**Complete Output:**

```
The highest populated element index is 4.

Array WS CountA              5 
Array WS Count               1 
Range WS CountA              3 
Range WS Count               1 
Range VBA .Count             5 

Array [For..Next] :
#1: Element value =         X
#2: Element value =          99 
#3: Element value =         Y

Range [For..Next] :
#1: Cell value =            X
#2: Cell value =             99 
#3: Cell value =            Y
```

---

### More Info:

- [IsEmpty Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/isempty-function)
- [UBound Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/ubound-function)
- [For...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/fornext-statement)

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using a custom class that contains an array variable, code to add items to the array which would also modify another variable to track the "used" index number. Then you could include a function to return the stored "highest index" number.

Answer (score -1):

**Note from 2018**: This is wrong in Excel 365, and was probably wrong in Excel 2000. See the comments. But I'm leaving it up as an example of how using `Application.WorksheetFunction()` from VBA isn't always exactly doing the same thing as using a formula in the worksheet.

---

Of course, there's really nothing wrong with looping, but...

Say you have this:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim a(1 To 3)

    a(1) = 1
    a(2) = "stuff"

    Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(a)
End Sub
```

That will print <s>'2'</s> [***No, it prints `3`** - See Comment***], since the third element has a default value of 'Empty'. (Note that your array has to be declared as type Variant for this to work, but it can contain elements of type String. If your array is of type String, there aren't any empties!) And of course, this assumes that you know all your empties are at the end, since it's just counting, not actually returning an index. For the same reason, you'd have to know the distribution of your values in a 2-D array for this to be meaningful.

I think this is what you're looking for, based on your edit.

Comment: **I'm surprised nobody else commented on this** in 8 years, but ***this is completely false!***  Copy-and-pasting your example returns **`3`**, not **`2`**.  Did you not test your code before posting it, or has the functionality of a fundamental Excel-VBA command changed in the past 8 years?

Comment: @ashlee, it looks like you're right. I think I would have pasted that code into the answer straight from the VBA editor since I was using it all the time back then. Pride makes me want to go find an XP machine with Excel 2000 loaded and check the result on that, but I agree it's not likely that anything has changed about calling worksheet functions from VBA even in the last 18 (not 8!) years. More likely I made an assumption based on how COUNTA works in the worksheet and it was wrong. So nice catch. Thanks.

Comment: Hey no problem, I recently looked back at some of my early answers here and was shocked @ myself, I ended up deleting half of them and editing the rest!  When I saw your answer I thought I was learning a cool new trick and spent a while trying to get it to work.... I suppose I may as well add an answer showing how I ended up solving my issue.

Comment: **Side Note** re: your observation about `Application.WorksheetFunction` not behaving the same in VBA as with a worksheet formula: in the case of `COUNT` it actually *will* behave the same, but giving it ranges versus arrays will not produce the same result, and it also makes a difference whether the values are numeric or text.  On the other hand, the Worksheet & VBA versions of `TRIM` are quite different.  (Test them with consecutive spaces in the middle of a string.)